# как получить данные из готового api jquery и вставить их в html

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

У меня есть код html

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
                <div id="pname" class="text-muted"></div>
                <div id="pdate" class="text-muted"></div>
                <br>
                <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
```

Так же есть код обращения к данным через ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: '****',
type: 'GET',
dateType: 'json',
success  : function (data) {
    //change i < 1 to i < len
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < 1; i++) {
        //debugger
        data[i].name;
        $( "#pname" ).append( data[i].author.name );
        $("#img").attr('src', data[i].author.avatar);
        $( "#pdate" ).append( data[i].author.created_at );
        $( "#content").append( data[i].content );

    }
},
data: {
    _method: 'GET'
}
```

});

Вот API. В нем есть массив и есть дочерние элементы (ответы на комментарии)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вставить все данные в нужные места в html?

Comment: Начать с того, что в вопросе убрать скриншоты и вставить реальный код

Comment: Что Вас не устраивает в коде, который у Вас уже есть?

Comment: мне нужно, что бы вывелся целый массив
что бы данные не выводились в одно место если я измени i< 1 на i<len

Comment: или Вы внятно объясняете, что Вам нужно, или я за себя не ручаюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log("Check the presence of container (expected 1):", $(".all-content").length);
$.ajax({
  url: '****',
  type: 'GET',
  dateType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Count of data items: ", data.length);
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
      var $block = $(`<div class="col-lg-10">
  <div class="pname text-muted"></div>
  <img />
  <div class="pdate text-muted"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>`);

      $block.find(".pname").text(data[i].author.name);
      $block.find("img").attr('src', data[i].author.avatar);
      $block.find(".pdate").text(data[i].author.created_at);
      $block.find(".content").text(data[i].content);
      $(".all-content").append($block);
    }
    console.log("Count of data blocks: ", $(".all-content > div").length);
  },
  data: {
    _method: 'GET'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-content">
</div>
```

Comment: У меня не работает выше написанное

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Как Вы думаете, слово "не работает" очень информативно для меня? Что это значит? Маленький гномик высунулся из компьютера, подмигнул и сказал "Не работает!"?

Comment: Вставляя ссылку на API я получаю 0 данных display - так понятно?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Вы неаккуратно скопировали мой код. Это бывает. К примеру, Вы не добавили в разметку `<div class="all-content"></div>`.

Comment: нет, я задал весь код на codopen и получаю в ответ чистый body

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Добавьте, пожалуйста, вызовы `console.log` - как у меня, и посмотрите, что в консоли браузера.

Comment: "Check the presence of container (expected 1):" 1

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич И все? А остальные `console.log`?

Comment: Ты лучший, я идиот - вот итог